# in ViewPager 2 while Dynamically remove Fragment ,It always Remove Last Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

in ViewPager 2  while Dynamically remove Fragment ,It always Remove Last Fragment but no problem during add fragment,i tried to give an id for each Fragment entry not worked ,but getItemPosition Override method work in Viewpager but not available in Viewpager2

please help me to solve this ,it haunting me lot of days

ViewPagerFragmentAdapter

```
public class ViewPagerFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

private ArrayList<Fragment> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();


public ViewPagerFragmentAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
    super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
   



}
@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment createFragment(int position) {


    return Test_FRAG.newinstance(position);
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}




public void addFragment(Test_FRAG test_frag) {
    arrayList.add(test_frag);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public void removefragment(int position) {

    arrayList.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();


}}
```

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager2 myViewPager2;
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPagerFragmentAdapter myAdapter;

int P;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    myViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    myViewPager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
    myAdapter = new ViewPagerFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());




    
    myAdapter.addFragment(new Test_FRAG());
    myAdapter.addFragment(new Test_FRAG());



    myViewPager2.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    myViewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(false);
    new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, myViewPager2,
            new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
                    tab.setText("Tab " + (position + 1));
                }
            }).attach();





    myViewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);

            Log.e("Selected_Page", String.valueOf(position));
            String info = String.valueOf(position);
            P = position;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
        }
    });

    // set Orientation in  ViewPager2
    myViewPager2.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);

    // myViewPager2.setPageTransformer(new MarginPageTransformer(1500));


}

public void ADD_Fragment(View view) {

    myAdapter.addFragment(new Test_FRAG());
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    myViewPager2.setCurrentItem(tabLayout.getTabCount());
    tabLayout.setSelected(true);

}

public void Close_Fragment(View view) {

  int pos = myViewPager2.getCurrentItem();
    myAdapter.removefragment(pos);
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are targeting the wrong fragment!

`arrayList.remove(getItemCount())` will always remove your last fragment (which happens to correspond with your fragment count).

Use the position instead. Something like: `arrayList.remove(position)`

Comment: Perfect answer, I was about to write down but I saw yours

Comment: Hi @Ragesh, I think there are some things missing in the code snippets you've shared.

I am not able to trace where the `ADD_Fragment` and `Close_Fragment` methods are called.

There's also a questionable initialization of `P = position` in the `onPageSelected` method. Please clarify. Regards!